# Counting Question for a Cartesian Coordinate

Tags: combinatorics

Consider a person who starts at the origin in the Cartesian plane (i.e., in the (x, y) plane). He takes four steps, each of length 1. Each step is left, right, up, or down. So there are 4 x 4 x 4 x 4 = 256 outcomes, corresponding to the 256 paths that he might choose to take. How many outcomes (i.e., 4-step-paths) will put him back at the origin, after the four steps are done?

The answer key says that there are 4 choose 2 (i.e., two left's and two right's) + 4 choose 2 (i.e., two up's and two down's) + 4! total paths. Why wouldn't we consider the case of three up's and one down's, for example?

Comment: I wouldn't consider it, since then the person is not at the origin.

Comment: Could you explain by what you mean with a hypothetical situation? I'm struggling to this understand this solution.

Comment: Just get a chess piece or a coin, and a piece of paper, and draw the Cartesian plane as far as $(-4,0),(+4,0),(0,+4),(0,-4)$ and actually do it.

Comment: Yeah I did - why would we count the two left's and two right's & two up's and two down's together instead of  any mix match of lefts and downs or rights and ups)?

Comment: @311411 To completely clarify my confusion, say someone is at (-4,0). We will need a move of 4 right's to reach the origin. However, in the solution, we are only counting two left's and two right's + two up's and two down's + 4! (i.e., each step is a unique path). How come we do not count the 4 right's in this case.

Comment: @311411 4 choose 2.

Comment: In your first sentence, you say we always start at the origin. So the only way our guy can arrive at (-4,0) is after his last move.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the man starts at the origin and ends at the origin, then his total displacement must be $0$.

This means the $x$ and $y$ displacement must both be $0$, which implies the number of left moves equals the number of right moves and the number of up moves equals the number of down moves.

Paths such as $3$ ups and $1$ down lead to the man ending up on $(0,2)$. Since the man is not ending up on the origin, we do not count this path.

If $L$ is the number of left moves, and define $R,U,D$ with similar, intuitive definitions, then we have
$$L=R$$
$$U=D$$
$$L+R+U+D=4$$
We can make substitutions of the first 2 equations into the last equation to get
$$L+L+U+U=4$$
$$2L+2U=4$$
$$L+U=2$$
Since $L,U,R,D$ are nonnegative integers, we can see that the only solutions are
$$L=0,U=2$$
$$L=1,U=1$$
$$L=2,U=0$$
We can now do casework on all these solutions

**Case 1:** $L=0,U=2$
Then $R=0$ and $D=2$. There are $\binom{4}{2}$ ways to arrange the $U$'s and $D$'s

**Case 2:** $L=1,U=1$
Then $R=1$ and $D=1$. There are $\binom{4}{1,1,1,1}=4!$ ways to arrange these moves

**Case 3:** $L=2,U=0$
Then $R=2$ and $D=0$. There are $\binom{4}{2}$ ways to arrange the $L$'s and $R$'s

The total is then $\binom{4}{2}+4!+\binom{4}{2}=\boxed{36}$.

Comment: This is explained so intuitively. Thank you for the help.